# How to restore a curtain pole where the rawl plugs have torn themselves out of the wall

Tags: hole, uk, curtain-rail

My curtain pole has fallen down tearing the rawl plugs out with it and leaving two messy holes.

How can I get the curtain pole back up securely? Ideally in the same holes so that it covers the damage and the curtains are in the same place, though I suppose I could move it horizontally then refill the old holes?

The wall appears to be plasterboard.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did someone hang on the curtain rod, or pull hard on it? I'm surprised to see the high-quality drywall anchor at right having pulled out. Those are rated for significant force. (Although I see that you didn't use them for all the screws. If you do go into drywall next time, I would suggest using high-quality anchors for all screws, using as many screws as possible, and definitely staying well away from the existing damaged holes.)

Answer (score 2):

Go buy toggle bolts and fender washers (I have seen them up to 2"in diameter) or some other large washer to cover the holes. You could also make a wooden washer out of some pre-finished wood or look for some kind of hanger hardware that will cover the holes and reinstall the curtain hanger. Take the bolt off the toggle, insert it through the curtain rod hanger, then add the washer, and last the toggle. Push the assembly into and through the old hole in the wall and tighten the toggle bolt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you properly repair the plasterboard. There are plenty of questions here and advice on the interwebz in general about how to do so.

Then, since your repair will likely lead you to finding the studs behind the plasterboard, I'd recommend that when you rehang the curtain rod, you bypass the rawl plugs/mollys/toggle bolts entirely by mounting the hangar brackets with longer screws that go directly into studs. Since it seems your poles go well beyond the window, there's nothing that will prevent you from having the hangars in from the ends so they do go into wood, it just means that you can't open the curtains all the way to expose the wall beside the window (you don't really want to do that anyway, do you?).

As an added bonus to the proper repair method, when you move out at the end of your lease you won't lose your damage deposit and/or when you go to sell, you'll really need to have this fixed up for the home inspection anyway.

Comment: I agree with Freeman, there is no reason to not be attaching into a stud. Take this opportunity to place the curtains at the proper height  what ever spacing you choose.